# Need help in developing iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am newbie to iOS/Swift.
I am developing app using Swift4 on XCode12.
But I have a problem with presenting UIViewController.

Below is my code:

- presenting UIViewController

  ```
  let scanner = NewController({ ... })
  scanner.delegate = self
  self.present(scanner, animated: true, completion: nil)
  ```
- NewController

  ```
  public class NewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    ...
  }
  ```

But it shows like this image.
[Image before/after presenting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuFX0.png)

As you can see in the image, it shows black margin after presenting NewController.

Anybody can help me?

I tested on simulator iPhone 8 (iOS 14.2).

Comment: Are you developing developing Swift4??? Or you are using developing Swift4??

Comment: I am developing iPhone app using Swift4.

Comment: Okay. Seems like some constraint issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. How can I solve it?

Comment: If possible please attach storyboard screen ss and describe related constraint

Comment: It has no storyboard. I made UI dynamically. The strange thing is that black margin appears when I present empty UIViewController.

`override public func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
}`
This is viewWillAppear function of NewController, then blank UI appears with black margin.

Answer (score 0):

This is the current UX that comes with presenting a View Controller modally. This is the expected output. If you want your view controller to take over the whole screen use `pushViewController` instead.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scanner, animated: true)
```

Use `popViewController` to dismiss your view controller.

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried above code, but 'scanner' is not displayed.